# Send message to specific Port (2000) in command line

Tags: command-line, cmd, udp, port

i wanted to send a mensgem from my computer to the Port 2000 through my computer on my command line !?!

Someone help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In order to send a message you first must understand in what language is the port 2000 speaking and who you want to send a message.

First you should know with who you wanna speak (The IP address of the machine)
Second you should know if this machine will able to hear you (Is the port 2000 open?)
Third you should know what "language" is the port 2000 hearing (The protocol of the open port)

First scan it with nmap to check if the port is open (-p 2000) and what software it's running (-sV), then send a packet with netcat ("nc IP 2000" and then send the content).

That's all i can help you with the information you provided.

Regards

Comment: desde já obrigado pela sua ajuda. sim eu tenho a certeza que o Port esta a escuta... o pacote a enviar é um UDP. logo gostaria de mandar um pacote UDP para a porta 200 que esta a escuta na linha de comandos.

Comment: Sorry i don't speak Portuguese. According to what i understand you can't send a UDP packet without installing anything in Windows since it's Telnet Client establish a TCP connection. You could in Linux tho.

Comment: No problem mate. I'm here to help you.

If what you are trying to do is do it from a Software you are writting perhaps you could implement some library.

Answer (score -1):

If by "command-line" you mean a unix-like system, then `nc` (short for netcat, sometimes also present under its full name `netcat`) is your friend.  If you specifically meant the *Windows* command-line then there's the option of installing netcat as part of http://cygwin.com , or there's a port of `nc` to Windows as part of this project:  http://www.brutman.com/mTCP/

Comment: Good morning, thanks for the reply. I mean the cmd windows, and wanted to send a message to the UDP Port 2000 without installing anything... is this possible?

Comment: Some versions of Windows have `telnet` available from the command-line, so you could try that.  But bear in mind that some Windows distributions don't come with it. If there's any other built-in tool, I'm unaware of it. That's one of the problems with Windows: you nearly always need third-party tools to get anything useful done, even really basic stuff.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:udp], so none of the Telnet options apply.

Comment: @user207421 True. I have edited the answer